# Combine Two SSD into one Bootable Drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd

So, Got new PC, moving things from old to new PC, and Was wondering, if I have the two SSD, Lets Say A and B, With A having the OS on it. I want to add B to A So they will share space, but it still be a bootable drive. I have read some sources and think it is possible, but I want to be sure, and want to know the correct steps.

OS: Windows 10

Both SSD are 256 GB

Comment: You may be able to achieve this using "Storage Spaces" under Control Panel. Exactly how I can't say for sure as I have never used it. Description from Storage Spaces `... Storage Spaces also lets you easily add more drives if you run low on capacity...` so hopefully that can do what you want. If someone else have tried using it to share their experience?

Comment: I read about this way, I was double checking if there was a better way, or if it was bad to do this with a boot ssd. Just going to Wait to see all the options, and thanks!

Comment: @Darius Windows can not boot from Storage Spaces, so this wont work...  Although here is says it might work: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2017/10/boot-from-storage-spaces-virtual-disk-in-windows-10/

Comment: There is a question on this site about the mentioned blog and booting from SP: https://superuser.com/questions/1400960/is-it-possible-to-boot-windows-1809-system-from-storage-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

If your motherboard supports hardware RAID you can set up a RAID 0 array with the two, then reinstall Windows. Many people here will tell you that this is a bad idea due to increased risk of data loss if one disk dies, and it also takes a fair bit of effort. But for high performance PCs with everything backed up regularly this can be an option worth considering.

Option 2 is [Storage Spaces](https://www.howtogeek.com/109380/how-to-use-windows-8s-storage-spaces-to-mirror-combine-drives/) as suggested by Darius. Setting up a combined storage space will wipe any data that was on the disks used, so not particularly useful with your boot drive.

Option 3 is to symbolically link the second disk into the first in a location that will gather lots of data. I'd suggest moving Program Files and Program Files (x86) to the second disk and [sym linking](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1557e84f-591a-46bb-86c4-3b38af2003b0/can-i-replace-the-program-files-folder-with-a-symbolic-link-to-another-drive?forum=w7itprogeneral) them back to the C: drive so that it looks like they are where they were originally. Program data would install to the second disk, while Windows and your Documents would stay on the first disk, but everything would be accessible via C:\
 You would still see the second drive as D: and could access the data on it via D: also. 
This option should work without too many issues other than occasional minor confusion over the fact that you can get to the same files via 2 paths.

Comment: Afaik, Storage Spaces isn't normally bootable. (An exception is the Surface Pro which has a UEFI module that enables this.)